# How to take a raspberry pi project and get it mass produced

Tags: pcb-design, raspberry-pi, production

I was wondering how can I take my project that I have done with a raspberry pi and convert it to a PCB for mass production.

My project is an e paper display that is attached to the raspberry pi in order to generate a menu for a user to interact with. The project was designed so I could give my employees a way to log data easier.

The issue is that the raspberry pi is not available on 123d circuit design for the PCBs. Is there another low power computer I can base this off of? Or is there a way to create your own raspberry pi based board for mass distribution?

I have seen the raspberry pi compute modules but I cannot find a connector for them in 123d.

I am a complete newbie to designing PCB so any advice would really help?

Comment: (1) Too broad. (2) [Duplicate.](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/192589/who-can-i-hire-to-mass-produce-tablet-type-electronic-project-based-off-raspberr) (3) Cloning a Rapberry Pi and mass producing it is a an extremely ambitious task for a first-timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you could make the board, you would not be able to get proprietary SoCs to populate it.  You will not be making your own Raspberry Pi. That said, there is a version of the Raspberry Pi designed to be used by [Original Equipment Manufacturers](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspberry-pi-compute-module-new-product/) (OEMs), but frankly, the price looks ludicrous.

There are similar computers on boards, like the Beaglebone Black, that don't use proprietary chips, that might be more friendly to your project.

If you just need a microcontroller, and not a full computer, your options go way up.